# getting a type error in google colab that was running just fine

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

```
temp_arr = -np.sort(-erray,axis=1)
ent_sum = np.zeros(erray.shape[0])
loc = np.zeros(erray.shape[0])
#print(erray[-2])
#print(temp_arr)
i = 0
for row in temp_arr:
  ent_sum[i] = sum(row)
  i += 1
  for col in row:
    if i == 1:
      print(col)
```

I am getting the following error in google colab:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-761acfbe346e> in <module>()
      6 i = 0
      7 for row in temp_arr:
----> 8   ent_sum[i] = sum(row)
      9   i += 1
     10   for col in row:

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

It was running just fine few minutes ago so I am curious about the reason for this error

Comment: the problem is you have made a variable named sum, and bow you are calling it as a function

Answer (score 0):

You have another variable name "sum"

Try

```
print (sum)
```